# Github personal access token for accessing private repository's: /repos/:user/:repo/contents

Tags: github, github-api, github-api-v3, github-api-v4

I am trying to use a **personal access token** for accessing the **contents** of a repository.

If the repository is public I can achieve this both with v3 and with v4 api. Both of the requests below return the contents:

**v3:**

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/w3c/webappsec/contents/
```

**v4:**

```
query {
  repository(owner: "w3c", name: "webappsec") {
    object(expression: "master:") {
      ... on Tree {
        entries{
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I have generated a personal access token for performing this operation in one of my private repositories, but it never returns anything:

**v3 (with Authorization token):**

```
curl -H "Authorization: bearer myauthorizationtoken" https://api.github.com/repos/myusername/myrepo/contents/
```

Result:

```
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents"
}
```

**v4 (with Authorization token):**

```
query {
  repository(owner: "myusername", name: "myrepo") {
    object(expression: "master:") {
      ... on Tree {
        entries{
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "object": null
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried checking all `read` checkboxes while generating the token but nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like, to obtain this information, all `repo` access rights for the token are required.

Works for me:

```
 [x] repo Full control of private repositories
     [x] repo:status Access commit status
     [x] repo_deployment Access deployment status
     [x] public_repo Access public repositories
     [x] repo:invite Access repository invitations
```

*Rights checkboxes*

API v3 usage:

```sh
$ curl -H "Authorization: bearer $private_token" https://api.github.com/repos/dmytrohoi/site.source/contents/

[
  {
    "name": ".github",
    "path": ".github",
    "sha": "hash",
    "size": 0,
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/dmytrohoi/site.source/contents/.github?ref=master",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/dmytrohoi/site.source/tree/master/.github",
    "git_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/dmytrohoi/site.source/git/trees/hash",
    "download_url": null,
    "type": "dir",
    "_links": {
      "self": "https://api.github.com/repos/dmytrohoi/site.source/contents/.github?ref=master",
      "git": "https://api.github.com/repos/dmytrohoi/site.source/git/trees/hash",
      "html": "https://github.com/dmytrohoi/site.source/tree/master/.github"
    }
  },
...
]
```

Comment: Thanks. It **works also with `v4`**. Strange having to request full repo control just to get file listing.